# MongoDB query is slow even when searching by indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection called calls containing properties `DateStarted, DateEnded, IdAccount, From, To, FromReversed, ToReversed`. In other words this is how a call document looks like:

```
{
     _id : "LKDJLDKJDLKDJDLKJDLKDJDLKDJLK",

     IdAccount: 123,
     
     DateStarted: ISODate('2020-11-05T05:00:00Z'),
     DateEnded:   ISODate('2020-11-05T05:20:00Z'),     
     
     From: "1234567890",
     FromReversed: "0987654321",
     
     To: "1231231234",
     ToReversed: "4321321321"
}
```

On our website we want to give customers the option to search by custom calls. When they search for calls they must specify the `DateStarted` and `DateEnded` Those fields are required the other ones are optional. The `IdAccount` will be injected on our end so that the customer can only get calls that belong to his account.

Because we have about 5 million records we have created the following indexes

```
db.calls.ensureIndex({"IdAccount":1});
db.calls.ensureIndex({"DateStarted":1});
db.calls.ensureIndex({"DateEnded":1});
db.calls.ensureIndex({"From":1});
db.calls.ensureIndex({"FromReversed":1});
db.calls.ensureIndex({"To":1});
db.calls.ensureIndex({"ToReversed":1});
```

> The reason why we did not created a compound index is because we want to be able to search by custom criteria. For example we may want to search by all calls with date smaller than December 11 and from a specific account.

Because of the indexes all these queries execute very fast:

```
db.calls.find({'DateStarted' : {'$gte': ISODate('2020-11-05T05:00:00Z')}).limit(200).explain();
db.calls.find({'DateEnded' : {'$lte': ISODate('2020-11-05T05:00:00Z')}).limit(200).explain();
db.calls.find({'IdAccount' : 123 ).limit(200).explain();
// etc...
```

Even queries that use regexes execute very fast. They only work fast if I use `^...` meaning that it must start with a search pattern as:

```
db.calls.find({  'From' : /^305/ ).limit(200).explain();
```

and that is the reason why we created the field `FromReversed` and `ToReversed`. If I want to search for a `To` phone number that ends with `3985` I will execute:

```
db.calls.find({  'ToReversed' : /^5893/ ).limit(200).explain(); // note I will have to reverse the search option to
```

So the only queries that are slow are the ones that do not start with something such as this query:

```
db.calls.find({  'ToReversed' : /1234/ ).limit(200).explain();
```

---

### Question

Why is it that if I combine all the queries it is very slow? For example this query is very slow:

```
db.calls.find({
  'DateStarted':{'$gte':ISODate('2018-11-05T05:00:00Z')}, 
  'DateEnded':{'$lte':ISODate('2020-11-05T05:00:00Z')},   
  'IdAccount':123,   
  'ToReversed' : /^5893/
}).limit(200).explain();
```

The problem is the `'ToReversed' : /^5893/`. If I execute that query by itself it is really fast. Even if I put something that does not give me the limit of 200 results fast. **Should I add a compound index as well? just for the scenario where it is slow**

I need to give our customers the option to search by phone numbers that end with or start with a specific criteria. The moment I add extra stuff to the query it becomes really slow.

---

### Edit

By researching on the internet if I use the `hint` option it is faster. It goes from 20 seconds to 5 seconds.

```
db.calls.find({
  'DateStarted':{'$gte':ISODate('2018-11-05T05:00:00Z')}, 
  'DateEnded':{'$lte':ISODate('2020-11-05T05:00:00Z')},   
  'IdAccount':123,   
  'ToReversed' : /^5893/
}).hint({'ToReversed':1}).limit(200).explain();
```

This is still slow and it will be great if I can lower it to 1 second just like the simple queries take milliseconds.

Comment: (1) In general, when specifying multiple criteria in query filter, using a compound index can improve the performance _over_ an index on a single field; I suggest try and verify the query plans and the usage of the compound index. Also, see [Create Compound Indexes to Support Several Different Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/index.html#create-compound-indexes-to-support-several-different-queries) (2) Using hints is not a very good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the find query you showed us involving filtering on 4 fields, ideally the optimal index would cover all 4 fields:

```js
db.calls.createIndex( {
    "DateStarted": 1,
    "DateEnded": 1,
    "IdAccount": 1,
    "ToReversed": 1
} )
```

As to which columns should appear first, you should generally place the most restrictive columns first.  Check the cardinality of your data to determine this.

Comment: Thanks again Tim! Even if I place the fields in a specific order I cannot be certain that the customer will want to filter the results by all fields. I wish I knew in advance what the customer intends to search for. So if I have the compund indexes `A,B,C,D` if the customer does not want to search by field `C` then it does not work :/

Comment: @TonoNam Not (entirely) true at all.  Let's say that the `IdAccount` has high cardinality such that you place it first in the index.  Then _any_ query which filters on `IdAccount` can potentially use this single index.  It won't be able to do an index seek, but Mongo would still potentially be able to scan the index.